# Casting changes value strangely

Tags: c++, casting

Why does `a1=72` instead of `73` in this (terrible) snippet of C++ code ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    double       a  = 136.73;
    unsigned int a1 = (100*(a-(int)a));

    cout << (a-(int)a)     << endl; // 0.73
    cout << 100*(a-(int)a) << endl; // 73
    cout << a1             << endl; // 72 !
}
```

You can execute it at http://codepad.org/HhGwTFhw

Comment: The answer should be related to precision. Asked many times in SO before.

Comment: Do you know about the binary representation of IEEE754 floating point numbers and the inherent limits when it comes to approximating decimal numbers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you increase the output precision, you'll see that `(a - (int) a)` prints `0.7299999999999898`.

Therefore, the [truncation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation) of this value (which you obtain when you cast it to an `int`) is indeed `72`.

(Updated codepad [here](http://codepad.org/V7JcDNVO).)

Answer (score 5):

This is a common precision issue. The literal `136.73` actually stands for the number

```
136.729999999999989768184605054557323455810546875
```

and the result of `a-(int)a` is not `0.73` (even though that is what is displayed), but rather

```
0.729999999999989768184605054557323455810546875
```

When you multiply that by `100`, you get

```
72.9999999999989768184605054557323455810546875
```

And since converting from double to int cuts off everything after the decimal point, you get `72`.

Comment: Where do the decimals after the nines come from ?

Comment: @Klaus: Read about how a double is internally stored and it should become obvious.

Answer (score 4):

`0.73` cannot be represented exactly so it is rounded to a number close to it, which in this example is lower then `0.73`. when multiplying by 100, you get `72.[something]`, which is later trimmed to `72`.

[more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format)

Answer (score 4):

It might become clear if you read the following article: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

The others have already shown that the result of `(a - (int)a)` is not exactly 0.73, but a little lower. The article explains **why** that is so. It is not exactly an easy read, but really something everyone working with FP should read and try to understand, IMO.